# Firestore data aggregation of documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an expense tracker app, where the user can set a monthly budget (ie. $3,000) and a  field 'total spending for the month' would update each time a user adds an expense. How would I do this using Firestore Database? So far, I have the expense record stored in a subcollection inside a document (using user-id) inside a user's collection.

```
  expenseForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('expense-record').doc().set({
      title: expenseTitle.value,
      amount: expenseAmount.value,
      category: expenseCategory.value,
      date: expenseDate.value,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooh, that's a fun use-case.

If you want to prevent the user from ever spending more than their budget, I'd:

1. Store the budget somewhere in the database.
2. Store the aggregate spending for the current month too, and use security rules to ensure that every expense record added/deleted also updates the aggregate spending for the month.
3. Use security rules to reject spend records that would push the aggregate over their budget.

These are non-trivial, but they would allow you to have a purely client-side solution. I imagine others may answer with solutions like Cloud Functions, which are totally valid too.

Comment: How exactly would I aggregate the spending using firestore? Would I need to use a transaction?

Comment: A transaction of a batch write indeed. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding transactions for my use-case since I can only increment by a set value rather than the amount of the expense.

Comment: You can increment by any amount, either in a transaction based on your own client-side logic or in a batched write with an `increment` operation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value